# How can I rollback on github, even just locally?

Tags: github, rollback

I'm working on an old project that has a partner who doesn't work on it any more. I tried to push my changes and saw that he had made some changes to the master on the repo. I pulled the changes and now everything is broken. It worked perfectly before I pulled his changes. How can I fix this, even if it is just rolling back locally?

Comment: 1. Make sure you have a complete backup of your local folder, I don't want to be (partially) responsible for you losing anything. 2. Figure out which commit you want to roll back to. 3. Execute a `git reset --hard SHA_OF_THAT_COMMIT`. If you want to have an additional fallback plan to make it easier to roll forward again, add 1b. `git branch TEMP_BEFORE_ROLLBACK` to add a branch pointing to the current tip of the branch you want to roll back.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!!!!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen do you want to make your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If your situation is that:

- You have commits at the tip of your branch that you don't want
- You have not made additional commits after them that you want to keep
- You have not pushed your changes anywhere
- You have not merged your branch into any other branch
- You do not have uncommitted files in your working folder that you want to keep

*(**NOTE!** If any of the above assumptions doesn't hold for your situation, **do not** use the rest of this answer, instead edit your question with more details and leave a comment here)*

then you can do the following:

1. Make sure you have a backup of your local working folder and repository, this way you can experiment. If in doubt if you managed to make a complete backup, experiment on the backup itself and leave the original folder untouched
2. Identify the hash of the commit you want to restore to, this should be the last commit before the ones you want to get rid of, ie. like this:

   ```
             You want to get rid of these
                        |
                    +---+---+
                    v   v   v
    O---O---O---O---X---X---X
                ^
                |
    get the hash of this commit
   ```
3. Reset back to that commit, using the following command

   ```
    git reset --hard HASH_OF_THAT_COMMIT
   ```

Note that after you have done this your working folder will be clean, your local branch will be back at the commit you identified and if you do a `git status`, it will show that you're behind the upstream (3 behind in the above example), since the upstream still have those extra commits that you just removed locally.

Comment: Note that after doing this, you cannot push, as this will first require you to pull, and then you'll have those incorrect commits back. If you also want to get rid of them permanently, on GitHub as well, you need to take extra steps. (I don't want to detail those here to keep this a simple answer)